# iText7 C# how extract (CROP/CLIP?) part of template larger than A4 to merge with an A4 PDF and result in A4?

Tags: c#, itext7

I have a template PDF that is slightly larger than A4 and has cross hairs near each corner to indicate the A4 size part of page. How should I look to extract that centered A4 part from the oversized PDF to merge with another PDF that is A4 and produce a final A4 PDF?

---

So breaking this down to the template crop/clip issue. I have used this code adapted from a Java example. It does appear to Crop/Clip as I wish ... except it still ends up with the original template page size (bigger than A4) not A4 as I was expecting / wanting?
Then I have to work out how to merge with the pdf that contains text to be merged with the template once it is A4.

```
private void manipulatePdf(string sTemplate, string sDoc, string sOutput)
{
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(sOutput));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4);
    doc.SetMargins(0f,0f,0f,0f);
    PdfDocument docTemplateA4Plus = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sTemplate));
    PdfDocument docTextA4 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sDoc));
    PdfPage pageTemplateA4Plus = docTemplateA4Plus.GetPage(1);
    PdfPage pageTextA4 = docTextA4.GetPage(1);
    iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle mediaBoxTemplateA4Plus =  pageTemplateA4Plus.GetMediaBox();
    iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle mediaBoxTextA4 = pageTextA4.GetMediaBox();
    float template_llx = mediaBoxTemplateA4Plus.GetX();
    float template_lly = mediaBoxTemplateA4Plus.GetY();
    float template_w = mediaBoxTemplateA4Plus.GetWidth();
    float template_h = mediaBoxTemplateA4Plus.GetHeight();
    float text_llx = mediaBoxTextA4.GetX();
    float text_lly = mediaBoxTextA4.GetY();
    float text_w = mediaBoxTextA4.GetWidth();
    float text_h = mediaBoxTextA4.GetHeight();
    float llx = ((template_w - text_w) / 2);
    float lly = ((template_h - text_h) / 2);
    float w = text_w;
    float h = text_h;
    docTemplateA4Plus.CopyPagesTo(1,1,pdfDoc);
    string sCommand = "\nq " + llx.ToString() + " " + lly.ToString() + " " + w.ToString() + " " + h.ToString() + " re W n\nq\n";
    PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDoc.GetPage(1);
    new PdfCanvas(pdfPage.NewContentStreamBefore(), pdfPage.GetResources(), pdfDoc)
    .WriteLiteral(sCommand);
    new PdfCanvas(pdfPage.NewContentStreamAfter(), pdfPage.GetResources(), pdfDoc)
    .WriteLiteral("\nQ\nQ\n");
    doc.Close();
    pdfDoc.Close();
}
```

Comment: Consider setting the crop box of the large PDF pages to exactly A4 size before merging. Do you know the exact positions (coordinates) of the cross hairs? Or do you need to determine them automatically?

Comment: I don't know them as such, but when I printed it on an A3 printer with no scaling if I put an A4 over it lines up pretty neat. I tried some code re "GetCropBox" but it returned null

Comment: *""GetCropBox" but it returned null"* - that should not happen, current versions of iText 7 both respect that the crop box defaults to the media box and that either value might be inherited. Which version exactly do you use? Can you share the PDF in question?

Comment: iText7 v7.1.10 via nuget package.
Unfortunately I can't share the PDF.
I would want to know if there is no Crop marks specified and the GetMediaBox will return the oversized page size, I need to take the centered A4 portion of it.

Comment: If you are sure that it's the centered portion, you can of course cut down to that without looking for the marks.

Comment: it looks centered in Adobe Reader. What would be best way to cut down? For merging into another doc to be A4?

Comment: Are there actual cross hairs (in all directions) or only along the actual page borders? And is there any content outside the crop area (e.g. color palettes)?

Comment: Ah just outer directions i.e. top left has one going up and to the left. There is some text relating to template type and version in the (non printing) boundary area.

Comment: Hhmmm, that's unfortunate. If it was only inwards and without extra text, I'd have proposed determining the bounding box of the page content and cutting down to that, but that doesn't work in your case. Are there any criteria by which those extras (crop marks and outer text) can be recognized as such and either filtered or used directly to determine page dimensions (in case of the crop marks)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so to answer my own question, I'm not sure it is most elegant but to solve the page size I added

```
var rect = new Rectangle(llx,lly,w,h);
pdfPage.SetMediaBox(rect);
```

and for the merging i added the 5 new lines near bottom relating to canvas in my complete code below.

```
private void manipulatePdf(string sTemplate, string sDoc, string sOutput)
{
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(sOutput));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4);
    doc.SetMargins(0f,0f,0f,0f);
    PdfDocument docTemplateA4Plus = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sTemplate));
    PdfDocument docTextA4 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sDoc));
    PdfPage pageTemplateA4Plus = docTemplateA4Plus.GetPage(1);
    PdfPage pageTextA4 = docTextA4.GetPage(1);
    iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle mediaBoxTemplateA4Plus =  pageTemplateA4Plus.GetMediaBox();
    iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle mediaBoxTextA4 = pageTextA4.GetMediaBox();
    float template_llx = mediaBoxTemplateA4Plus.GetX();
    float template_lly = mediaBoxTemplateA4Plus.GetY();
    float template_w = mediaBoxTemplateA4Plus.GetWidth();
    float template_h = mediaBoxTemplateA4Plus.GetHeight();
    float text_llx = mediaBoxTextA4.GetX();
    float text_lly = mediaBoxTextA4.GetY();
    float text_w = mediaBoxTextA4.GetWidth();
    float text_h = mediaBoxTextA4.GetHeight();
    float llx = ((template_w - text_w) / 2);
    float lly = ((template_h - text_h) / 2);
    float w = text_w;
    float h = text_h;
    var rect = new Rectangle(llx,lly,w,h);
    docTemplateA4Plus.CopyPagesTo(1,1,pdfDoc);
    string sCommand = "\nq " + llx.ToString() + " " + lly.ToString() + " " + w.ToString() + " " + h.ToString() + " re W n\nq\n";
    PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDoc.GetPage(1);
    new PdfCanvas(pdfPage.NewContentStreamBefore(), pdfPage.GetResources(), pdfDoc)
    .WriteLiteral(sCommand);
    new PdfCanvas(pdfPage.NewContentStreamAfter(), pdfPage.GetResources(), pdfDoc)
    .WriteLiteral("\nQ\nQ\n");

    pdfPage.SetMediaBox(rect);

    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.GetFirstPage().NewContentStreamBefore(), pdfDoc.GetFirstPage().GetResources(), pdfDoc);
    PdfFormXObject page;
    srcDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(path));
    page = srcDoc.GetFirstPage().CopyAsFormXObject(pdfDoc);
    canvas.AddXObject(page, 0, 0);

    doc.Close();
    pdfDoc.Close();
}
```